# Often, after a maven refresh, unit testing of a project cannot find the module it declared itself in its module-info.java. Repair IDE, delete .idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module

My first module in my project list has ten unit tests and a `module-info.java` containing:

```java
module fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils {
   requires org.slf4j;
   requires org.apache.commons.lang3;

   exports fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils.objets;
   exports fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils.autocontrole;
}
```

that from a `mvn clean install` in a command line, compiles and succeed its tests.

---

Depending of an amount of luck, when I refresh the whole maven Project, either the project and its tests are also compiling, and the whole application is buildable and testable also from *IntelliJ 2023.2.5*,

either the tests launched from the IDE immediately stops with the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils not found
```

and a *Build Project* or a *Rebuild Project* attempting to rebuild all the application, will fail with the message:

```
module not found: fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils
module not found: org.slf4j
module not found: org.apache.commons.lang3
module not found: io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations
module not found: java.validation
```

But, if I rebuild only that module by right clicking on its context menu, the build will succeed and the unit tests also.

Because I cannot then build by IntelliJ the remaining of my application, I cannot it to test it anymore, and I have to switch to the command line to perform the building, with *Maven*.

---

When I stumble into this problem, currently, my workaround is too try *Repair IDE*, restart it, sometimes have to delete the `.idea` folder (but this causes me loosing all my personal settings), and at a time, *IntelliJ* restarts understanding the whole project well again.

But it's long. Very long. Each time this trouble happens, is often 1h30 I have to spend on it, and I would like to find a way to fix it quickly when it happens.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ?

Comment: `2023.2.5` I edited my post.

Comment: Sometimes I get this error when I switch to a different git branch - then the whole project is broken. My workaround is a combination of deleting everything in `~/.m2/repository` and deleting `.idea` directory. It works, but takes a long time. Invalidating Caches in IDEA doesn't do anything for me. I suspect it has something to do with memory management of IDEA (?).

Comment: _IntelliJ_ is in terrible shape these last months. I've even found _Yoututbe_ Java videos having to mention it during their demonstrations! A sign that we are not alone. I pray each day that IDEA stops adding new features for a while to stick on correcting bugs. It seems that my problem tend to resolve if I do not click on the "M" icon that appears when my Maven project changes, and go instead in the _Maven_ window to ask for a _Reload All Maven Projects_

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to stem from IDEA using its' own Build System for some of the options it offers (for instance, options from the "Build" menu are based on the Native Build System), even if the Project in question is Maven-based.

Native Build System tries to stick to Maven conventions, but there might be discrepancies, that may, in turn, lead to issues you are describing.

For Maven-based Projects it's best to use options from the [Maven Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) (and corresponding [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html)). You can also enable "[Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-runner.html)".

Might be a good idea to submit a [YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) with a reproducer Project attached, so this can be fully investigated and resolved.

Comment: The problem is that according to my experiences, you can delegate the build actions to Maven, and then the build succeeds, but when you ask to run a test, it performs "it's own" build procedure again and fails. But currently I think that it's the function "refresh maven project" who is faulty. If I do a complete reload of maven projects instead. it will succeed.